# How to highlight dates in a TextBlock MVVM Light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I want to highlight the foreground or background color of the dates based on current date. How can I do it in my ViewModel?

What are the codes I can use to highlight the date?

Here are my codes for the whole project:

xaml:

```
<Grid Margin="10,102,10,298">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Calendar.DateCollection}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="dateGrid"  Background="AntiqueWhite" Width="50" Height="30">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtDate" Text="{Binding}"  Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsTapEnabled="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Complete ViewModel:

```
DateTime calendarDate;

public calendarViewModel()
{
    calendarDate = DateTime.Today;
    Initialize_Calendar(calendarDate);
}

private ObservableCollection<string> _DATECollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> DateCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _DATECollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _DATECollection = value;
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Event> _eventCollection = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
public ObservableCollection<Event> EventCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _eventCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        _eventCollection = value;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="CalendarMonthYear" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string CalendarMonthYearPropertyName = "CalendarMonthYear";

private string _calendarMonthYear ;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the CalendarMonthYear property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public string CalendarMonthYear
{
    get
    {
        return _calendarMonthYear;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_calendarMonthYear == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _calendarMonthYear = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(CalendarMonthYearPropertyName);
    }
}

//button next month
private RelayCommand _nextMonth;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the NextMonth.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand NextMonth
{
    get
    {
        return _nextMonth
            ?? (_nextMonth = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                calendarDate = calendarDate.AddMonths(1);
                Initialize_Calendar(calendarDate);
            }));
    }
}

//Button previous month
private RelayCommand _previousMonth;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the PreviousMonth.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand PreviousMonth
{
    get
    {
        return _previousMonth
            ?? (_previousMonth = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                calendarDate = calendarDate.AddMonths(-1);
                Initialize_Calendar(calendarDate);
            }));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="DATE" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string DATEPropertyName = "DATE";

private string _date;

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the DATE property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
/// </summary>
public string DATE
{
    get
    {
        return _date;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_date == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _date = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(DATEPropertyName);
    }
}

public void Initialize_Calendar(DateTime date)
{
    CalendarMonthYear = date.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
    date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
    int dayOfWeek = (int)date.DayOfWeek + 1;
    int daysOfMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
    int i = 1;
    DateCollection.Clear();
    for (int d = 1; d <= daysOfMonth; d++ )
    {
        if (i >= dayOfWeek && i < (daysOfMonth + dayOfWeek))
        {
            DATE = (i - dayOfWeek + 1).ToString();
            DateCollection.Add(DATE);
        }
        else
        {
            DATE = "";
            DateCollection.Add(DATE);
            if (DATE == "")
            {
                daysOfMonth++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}

private RelayCommand _dateClick;

/// <summary>
/// Gets the DateClick.
/// </summary>
public RelayCommand DateClick
{
    get
    {
        return _dateClick
            ?? (_dateClick = new RelayCommand(
            async() =>
            {
                EventCollection.Clear();
                List<Event> E = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Event>().ToListAsync();
                    foreach(Event evnt in E)
                    {
                        if (evnt.Date.Date.Equals(DateTime.Today.Date))
                        {
                            EventCollection.Add(new Event
                                {
                                    Id = evnt.Id,
                                    EventName = evnt.EventName,
                                    Desc = evnt.Desc,
                                    Category = evnt.Category,
                                    Location = evnt.Location,
                                    StartingTime = evnt.StartingTime,
                                    Date = evnt.Date     
                                });
                        }

                    }
               if(EventCollection.Count == 0 )
                        {
                            MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog("Empty", "No Events today!.");
                            await m.ShowAsync();
                        }
            }));
    }
}
```

DateConverter Class:

```
public class DateColorConvertor : IValueConverter
{

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object();
    }

    public object Convert(object sender, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        DateTime currentItem = DateTime.Parse((sender as TextBlock).Text);
        if (currentItem == DateTime.Now) 
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the textbox contain text other than the date, and do you only want to highlight the date?  What happens if the textbox contains multiple dates? ie. "Today is 8/12/2015, tomorrow will be 8/13/2015"

Comment: its just a container which repeats itself for the dates in a month. i want to highlight the current date.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a converter to do that, this involves the following steps

1) create the converter class, it should implement the [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

2) Implement the `Convert` method, as I understand you want to do this based on current date so it should be like

//supposing that the date in your item is an a parseable format

```
DateTime currentItem = DateTime.Parse((sender as TextBlock).Text)
if(currentItem == DateTime.Now) // your comparison goes here
 return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
else
 return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Next step declare the namespace in your XAML Code

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1" // src is the name, PhoneApp1 the namespace
```

Then in the Grid add it in the resources

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <src:DateColorConverter x:Key="DateColorConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

Finally in your Textblock set the ForeGround to

```
Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateColorConverter}}"
```

What is essentially done here is that every object the will be binded in your lists, goes through a check and gets the value on the runtime.

You can also try checking [this example](http://studentguru.gr/b/infamous/archive/2013/11/07/ivalueconverter-runtime), it's in greek but with some google translate you'll understand how it works.

Comment: how do i implement the convert method i am somehow lost. i am new to c#

Comment: @user3411961just add the first portion of code I have posted in the convert method

Comment: sorry for late reply there are test going on. But how to add the type of the method since its return something? i know int string void float??

Comment: this is how i implemented the method:




`public object Convert()
        {
            DateTime currentItem = DateTime.Parse((sender as TextBlock).Text);
            if(currentItem == DateTime.Now) // your comparison goes here
                 return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }`

Comment: Methods return object, in C# everything inherits from System.Object.

Have you got it working?

Comment: no it giving me an error  for the sender stating that `The name sender does not exists in the current context`

Comment: It;s doing this because you haven't created the converter class and just copied the method. create a C# class with the following data http://pastebin.com/yk7bN0PE

Comment: it still does give me the error and when i try to resolve it i get either to generate a property stub or field stub

Comment: The problem is that you're copy / pasting code and that's why getting your errors, please read this article and I believe you'll understand the use of the converter http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF

Comment: sorry for late reply still because tests. So i did resolve all the errors, the error for the sender was that in the method convert() i had to insert object sender instead of object value. so now i am getting a `System.NullReferenceException` and additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.