# Pivot Header Text Color in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8.1 app, where I am not able to change the Pivot Text Header Color.

I have use below code in my pivot section, but here I can't use multi color in text blocks.

```
<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                        
          <Grid Height="40">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                          Foreground="Black"
                          FontSize="28"
                          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
          </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

Note : I need a solution for windows phone 8.1 and also I want to change the text color not the background color.

Comment: So the question is "How do I change the text color within a Pivot header template on Windows Phone 8.1"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different colours in every textbox have a look at this, you'll have to use a converter

[How to highlight dates in a TextBlock MVVM Light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970226/how-to-highlight-dates-in-a-textblock-mvvm-light/31970716#31970716)

Comment: I have to change the pivot header text color according as pivot section selected and deselected.

Comment: Subscribe to this event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selectionchanged(v=vs.105).aspx and according to the selected index, change the header